# Django Update view saving but not updating

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have made a working form to post reviews for restaurants.
When user is logged in he can see displayed under his post the edit button.
When I use the Updateview however, it doesn't edit, but instead creates a new line in which the new review appears (and that new line doesn't appear then on my webpage).
Here is the model:

```
class UserReview(models.Model):
    # Defining the possible grades
    Grade_1 = 1
    Grade_2 = 2
    Grade_3 = 3
    Grade_4 = 4
    Grade_5 = 5
    # All those grades will sit under Review_Grade to appear in choices
    Review_Grade = (
        (1, '1 - Not satisfied'),
        (2, '2 - Almost satisfied'),
        (3, '3 - Satisfied'),
        (4, '4 - Very satisfied'),
        (5, '5 - Exceptionally satisfied')
    )
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_review_grade = models.IntegerField(default=None, choices=Review_Grade) # default=None pour eviter d'avoir un bouton vide sur ma template
    user_review_comment = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    posted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('restaurants:reviews', args=[self.id])

    def get_edit_url(self):
        return reverse('restaurants:edit-review', args=(self.id,))
```

Here is the update form (similar as review form):

```
class EditReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserReview
        fields = [
            'restaurant',
            'user_review_grade',
            'user_review_comment'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'restaurant': forms.HiddenInput,
            'user_review_grade': forms.RadioSelect,
            'user_review_comment': forms.Textarea
        }
        labels = {
            'user_review_grade': 'Chose a satisfaction level:',
            'user_review_comment': 'And write your comments:'
        }
```

Here is the UpdateView:

```
class EditReview (LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    template_name = 'restaurants/review_edit.html'
    form_class = EditReviewForm
    model = UserReview
    slug = 'review'
    # Post the data into the DB
    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserReviewForm(request.POST)
        restaurant = get_object_or_404(Restaurant, pk=pk)
        if form.is_valid():
            edit_review = form.save(commit=False)
            form.instance.posted_by = self.request.user
            print(edit_review)  # Print so I can see in cmd prompt that something posts as it should
            edit_review.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('restaurants:details', args=[restaurant.id]))
        return render(request, 'restaurants/details.html', {'form': form})
```

Do you have any idea of what might be going wrong?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In update view, you forgot to add object instance to the form.

```
def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
     obj = get_object_or_404(UserReview, pk=pk)
     form = UserReviewForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
```

Comment: Thanks, silly me, I knew I was close but couldn't figure out where I was missing something.
I still have lots to learn!